# Problema com &quote ao gerar txt via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Caros, possuo uma rotina que cria um arquivo txt com algumas informações de uma consulta no mysql, porem quando a consulta retorna algum texto com aspas, o problema começa.
Quando exibo os dados na tela, as informações que possuem aspas dupla aparecem normalmente, por exemplo (texto "com" aspas), mas quando esses dados são salvos em um arquivo txt as aspas são substituídas por &quote (texto quote;com quote; aspas). Nao sei como resolver este problema.
Segue o código:

```
        <?PHP
    include_once("../../function/valida.php");
    include_once('../../function/funcoes.php');
    $ItemQTD = $_POST['Item'];
    $B12 = $_POST['nfeB12'];
    $CST = $_POST['CST'];
    $IPI=$_POST['IPI'];
    $PIS=$_POST['PIS'];
    $B15a=$_POST['B15a'];
    $COFINS=$_POST['COFINS'];
    $B9 = $_POST['B9'];
    $B15 = $_POST['B15'];
    $X26_382 = $_POST['X26_382'];
    $X26_383 = $_POST['X26_383'];
    $X26_387 = $_POST['X26_387'];
    $X26_386 = $_POST['X26_386'];
    $B29 = $_POST['B29'];
    $B02 = $_POST['B02'];
    $B02 = split(":",$B02);
    $b116 = $_POST['116b'];
    echo "I116b=$b116";
    $Z401 = $_POST['Z401'];
    $Y07 = $_POST['Y07'];
    $Y07[1]=MudaData($Y07[1]);
    if(!empty($Y07[3])){
    $Y07[3]=MudaData($Y07[3]);  
    }
    if(!empty($Y07[5])){
    $Y07[5]=MudaData($Y07[5]);  
    }

    $colunas ="
    A2,A3,A4,
    B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12,B13,B14,B15,B15A,B16,B25,B26,B27,B28,B29,B291,B292,B29A,B29B,B29C,B29D,
    B02,
    C32,C33,C46,C47,C48,C49,C49A,C02,C0535,C0536,C0537,C0538,C0539,C0540,C0541,C0542,C0543,C0544,C0545,
    E65,E77A,E78,E79,E791,E79A,E02,E03A,E0567,E0568,E0569,E0570,E0571,E0572,E0573,E0574,E0575,E0576,E0577,
    G91,G92,G93,G94,G95,G96,G97,G02,
    H99,
    I101,I102,I103,I104,I105,I106,I107,I108,I109,I110,I111,I112,I113,I113A,I114,I115,I116,I116A,I116B,I128A,I128B,
    N02166,N02167,N02168,N02169,N02170,N02171,N03173,N03174,N03175,N03176,N03177,N03178,N03179,N03180,N03181,
    N03182,N03183,N03184,N06203,N06204,N0620401,N0620402,
    O247,O248,O249,O250,O251,O07,O08,O10254,O10257,
    Q02269,Q02270,Q02271,Q02272,Q04,
    S02295,S02296,S02297,S02298,S04,
    W02328,W02329,W0232901,W02330,W02331,W02332,W02333,W02334,W02335,W02336,W02337,W02338,W02339,W02340,W02341,W02341A,
    X,X03361,X03362,X03363,X03364,X03365,X04,X26382,X26383,X26384,X26385,X26386,X26387,
    Y07396_1,Y07397_1,Y07398_1,Y07396_2,Y07397_2,Y07398_2,Y07396_3,Y07397_3,Y07398_3,Z400,Z401";
    $selectId = "select id from temp_nf";
    $selectId = mysql_query("select distinct id,b12 from temp_nf");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectId)){
    $query = "select $colunas from temp_nf where id=$row[id] order by i128b";
    $cont=0;
    $NFe = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
        //substituir valores vazios para null
            foreach($NFe as $x){
                if(empty($x)){
                    if($cont==9){
                    $x="'0000001'"; 
                    }else{
                        $x="null";
                    }
                }else{
                    $x = "'".$x."'";
                }
            $str2.=$x.",";
            $cont++;
            }
    $sql_query="insert into financeiro_nf (".$colunas.",data_modif,usuario) value (".$str2."now(),'$_SESSION[Usuario]')";
        if(isset($sql_query)){
            mysql_query($sql_query,$conexao);//usado o utf8 para que seja interpretado os char especiais na query
            $id=mysql_insert_id();
            //if ($error = mysql_errno()) echo("<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Erro 1 : ".mysql_errno().", contate o administrador\");</script>"); 
            if ($error = mysql_errno()) die("<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Erro 1 : ".mysql_errno().", contate o administrador\");history.back();</script>"); 
            echo $update."</br>";
                if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
                {
                }else
                {
                    echo "<script>alert(\"1 - Nenhum arquivo afetado \");</script>'";
                };
        };
    $NFe['I103'] = str_replace('"','',$NFe['I103']);
    $I.="
    H|$NFe[H99]|
    I|$NFe[I101]|$NFe[I102]|$NFe[I103]|$NFe[I104]|$NFe[I105]|$NFe[I106]|$NFe[I107]|$NFe[I108]|$NFe[I109]|$NFe[I110]|$NFe[I111]|$NFe[I112]|$NFe[I113]|$NFe[I113A]|$NFe[I114]|$NFe[I115]|$NFe[I116]|$NFe[I116A]|$b116|$NFe[I128A]|$NFe[I128B]|
    M|
    N|";
    if($CST=="00"){
    $I.="
    N02|$NFe[N02166]|$NFe[N02167]|$NFe[N02168]|$NFe[N02169]|$NFe[N02170]|$NFe[N02171]|";
    }else if($CST=="10"){
    $I.="
    N03|$NFe[N03173]|$NFe[N03174]|$NFe[N03175]|$NFe[N03176]|$NFe[N03177]|$NFe[N03178]|$NFe[N03179]|$NFe[N03180]|$NFe[N03181]|$NFe[N03182]|$NFe[N03183]|$NFe[N03184]|";
    }else if($CST=="40"){
    $I.="
    N06|$NFe[N06203]|$NFe[N06204]|$NFe[N0620401]|$NFe[N0620402]|";
    };
    $I.="
    O|$NFe[O247]|$NFe[O248]|$NFe[O249]|$NFe[O250]|$NFe[O251]|";
    if($IPI=="SIM"){
    $ipi = number_format(($NFe['O10254']*0.1),3);
    $I.="
    O07|$NFe[O07]|".Arredonda($ipi)."|
    O10|$NFe[O10254]|$NFe[O10257]|";    
    }else{
    $I.="
    O08|$NFe[O08]|";
    }
    $I.="
    Q|";
    if(!empty($NFe['E79'])){
    $I.="
    Q04|$NFe[Q04]|";    
        }else{
        if($PIS=="SIM"){
    $I.="
    Q02|$NFe[Q02269]|$NFe[Q02270]|$NFe[Q02271]|$NFe[Q02272]|";  
        }
    }
    $I.="
    S|";
    if($COFINS=="SIM"){
    $I.="
    S02|$NFe[S02295]|$NFe[S02296]|$NFe[S02297]|$NFe[S02298]|";  
    }else{
    $I.="
    S04|$NFe[S04]|";
    }
    $str2="";
    $sql_update = "
    update financeiro_nf set 
    B9='$B9',
    B15='$B15',
    B29='$B29',
    B02='$B02[1]',
    I116b='$b116',
    X26382='$X26_382',
    X26383='$X26_383',
    X26387='$X26_387',
    X26386='$X26_386',
    Y07397_1='$Y07[1]',
    Y07398_1='$Y07[2]',
    Y07397_2='$Y07[3]',
    Y07398_2='$Y07[4]',
    Y07397_3='$Y07[5]',
    Y07398_3='$Y07[6]',
    Z401='$Z401'
    where id='$id'
    ";
    $update=str_replace("''","null",$sql_update);
        if(isset($update)){
            mysql_query($update,$conexao);//usado o utf8 para que seja interpretado os char especiais na query
            $id=mysql_insert_id();
            if ($error = mysql_errno()) die($update."<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Erro 2 : ".mysql_errno().", contate o administrador\");</script>"); 
                if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
                {
                    $msg = "NFe Gerada com sucesso";
                    $aux=1;
                }else
                {
                    $msg="2 - Nenhum arquivo afetado";
                    $aux=0;
                };
        };
    $str2="";   
    $update="";
    };
    if($aux==1){
    $i=0;
    //Atualiza status de Item   
    foreach($ItemQTD as $x){
     $split=explode("|",$x);
     $Itempk[$i]=$split[0];
     if(!empty($split[1])){
         $un[$Itempk[$i]]=$split[1];
     }
     $i++;
    }
    foreach($Itempk as $x){
    $sql = "select unidades,n_ped_doberfk from financeiro_item where itempk=$x";
    $QTD_Item = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
    $UnAtual = $QTD_Item['unidades']-$un[$x];
        if($UnAtual==0){
            $Faturado = "update financeiro_item set status='FATURADO',NFe='$B12',unidades=$un[$x] where itempk=$x";
            mysql_query($Faturado);     
            if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
                {
                    //echo "<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"OK\");</script>";
                }else
                {
                    echo $Faturado;
                    echo "<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"ERRO STATUS FATURADO , contate o administrador\");</script>";
                };
        }else{
            $PARCIAL = "update financeiro_item set status='PARCIAL',NFe='$B12',unidades=$un[$x] where itempk=$x";
            mysql_query($PARCIAL);      
            if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
                {
                    //echo "<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"OK\");</script>";
                }else
                {
                    echo "<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"ERRO STATUS PARCIAL, contate o administrador\");</script>";
                };
        }   
    $sqlPedido="select count(status) as cont from financeiro_item 
    where
    n_ped_doberfk=$QTD_Item[n_ped_doberfk] 
    and
    status=\"PENDENTE\" or status = \"PARCIAL\"";
    $cont=  mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sqlPedido));
    if($cont['cont']=="0"){
    $up_ped = "update financeiro_pedido set status=\"FATURADO\" where n_ped_dober='$QTD_Item[n_ped_doberfk]'";
    mysql_query($up_ped);       
            if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
                {
                    //echo "<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"PEDIDO OK\");</script>";
                }else
                {
                    echo "<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"ERRO STATUS PEDIDO $up_ped, contate o administrador\");</script>";
                };
    }
        //echo $sql ."</br>";
    }   




    $sqlView = "select $colunas from financeiro_nf where b12 = $B12";
    $NFe = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sqlView));
    //echo $sqlView."</br>";
    $txt= "NOTA FISCAL|1|
    A|$NFe[A2]|$NFe[A3]|$NFe[A4]|
    B|$NFe[B6]|$NFe[B7]|$NFe[B8]|$NFe[B9]|$NFe[B10]|$NFe[B11]|$NFe[B12]|$NFe[B13]|$NFe[B14]|$NFe[B15]|$NFe[B15A]|$NFe[B16]|$NFe[B25]|$NFe[B26]|$NFe[B27]|$NFe[B28]|$NFe[B29]|$NFe[B291]|$NFe[B292]|$NFe[B29A]|$NFe[B29]|$NFe[B]|$NFe[B29C]|$NFe[B29D]|";
    if($B29!="1"){
    $txt.="B02|$NFe[B02]|"  ;
    }
    $txt.="
    C|$NFe[C32]|$NFe[C33]|$NFe[C46]|$NFe[C47]|$NFe[C48]|$NFe[C49]|$NFe[C49A]|
    C02|$NFe[C02]|
    C05|$NFe[C0535]|$NFe[C0536]|$NFe[C0537]|$NFe[C0538]|$NFe[C0539]|$NFe[C0540]|$NFe[C0541]|$NFe[C0542]|$NFe[C0543]|$NFe[C0544]|$NFe[C0545]|
    E|$NFe[E65]|$NFe[E77A]|$NFe[E78]|$NFe[E79]|$NFe[E791]|$NFe[E79A]|
    E02|$NFe[E02]|";
    if($B15a=="3"){
    $txt.="
    E03a|$NFe[E03A]|"   ;
    }
    $txt.="
    E05|$NFe[E0567]|$NFe[E0568]|$NFe[E0569]|$NFe[E0570]|$NFe[E0571]|$NFe[E0572]|$NFe[E0573]|$NFe[E0574]|$NFe[E0575]|$NFe[E0576]|$NFe[E0577]|";
    if(!empty($NFe['G91'])){
    $txt.="
    G|$NFe[G91]|$NFe[G92]|$NFe[G93]|$NFe[G94]|$NFe[G95]|$NFe[G96]|$NFe[G97]|
    G02|$NFe[G02]|";
    }
    $txt.=$I;
    $txt.="
    W|
    W02|$NFe[W02328]|$NFe[W02329]|$NFe[W0232901]|$NFe[W02330]|$NFe[W02331]|$NFe[W02332]|$NFe[W02333]|$NFe[W02334]|$NFe[W02335]|$NFe[W02336]|$NFe[W02337]|$NFe[W02338]|$NFe[W02339]|$NFe[W02340]|$NFe[W02341]|$NFe[W02341A]|
    W23||||||||
    X|$NFe[X]|
    X03|$NFe[X03361]|$NFe[X03362]|$NFe[X03363]|$NFe[X03364]|$NFe[X03365]|
    X04|$NFe[X04]|
    X26|$NFe[X26382]|$NFe[X26383]|$NFe[X26384]|$NFe[X26385]|$NFe[X26386]|$NFe[X26387]|
    Y|
    Y07|$NFe[Y07396_1]/01|$NFe[Y07397_1]|$NFe[Y07398_1]|";
    if(!empty($NFe['Y07396_2'])){
    $txt.="
    Y07|$NFe[Y07396_2]/02|$NFe[Y07397_2]|$NFe[Y07398_2]|";
    };
    if(!empty($NFe['Y07396_3'])){
    $txt.="
    Y07|$NFe[Y07396_3]/03|$NFe[Y07397_3]|$NFe[Y07398_3]|";
    };
    $txt.="
    Z|$NFe[Z400]|$NFe[Z401]|";
    $data=date("d_m_Y");
    $AnoMes = date("Ym");
    $filename = "NFe/$AnoMes";
    if (!(file_exists($filename))) {
    mkdir("NFe/$AnoMes", 0777);
    }
    $nome="NFe_".$B12."_MTZ_1_".$data;
    $diretorio = "//Versao 310";
    if (!file_exists($diretorio)) {
        mkdir($diretorio, 0700);
    }
    $arquivo = fopen("$diretorio/$nome.txt", "w");
    //$texto = ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "", strtr($txt, "áàãâéêíóôõúüçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÇ ", "aaaaeeiooouucAAAAEEIOOOUUC_"));
    $texto=addslashes($txt);
    //$texto = preg_replace('/(\'|")/', "", $texto);
    fwrite($arquivo, $texto);
    fclose($arquivo);
    //echo $nome;
    echo "<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"$msg $nome\");history.go(-2);</script>";  
    }else{
    echo "<script type\"text/javascript\">alert(\"$msg $nome\");history.go(-2);</script>";      
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Postar seu código em PHP / MySQL ajudaria muito a elaborar uma resposta, sem ele não dá pra identificar o que está substituindo os caracteres.

Comment: Olá, me desculpe, acabei de colocar o código. Obrigado

Comment: Já tentou definir através de atalhos: Para (“) é: ALT+0147 e para (”) é: ALT+0148

Answer (score 0):

Faça um replace antes de escrever:

```
str_replace("quote;", '"', $texto);
```

Ou

```
str_replace(chr(39), '"', $texto);
```

Comment: Marcelo,obrigado pela resposta, porem eu ja havia tentado este procedimento. Mas esse problema acontece depois que o arquivo é salvo, se eu exibir o conteudo de $texto vai aparecer tudo certinho, ele só aparece o quot depois de salvo em txt.